# CSS Hover - Fade in on hover, Disappear instantly off hover

Tags: html, css

So, I have a hover transition that I would like to ease in on hover, but be instantaneous off hover.

Here's a sample snippet:

```css
.invisible{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

div{
  cursor: pointer;
}

div:hover .invisible{
  opacity: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hover Here</p>
  <p class="invisible">Now you see me</p>
</div>
```

What can I change in the CSS to keep the text fading in over the space of 1 second, but instantly vanish when the mouse is moved away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give transition to hover state only, by default it was given to all states.

Once you'll use it for `:hover`, transition will occur only for mouseover, not for mouseout.

```css
.invisible {
  opacity: 0;
}

div {
  cursor: pointer;
}

div:hover .invisible {
  opacity: 100%;
  transition: 1s; /* moved this */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hover Here</p>
  <p class="invisible">Now you see me</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify a different transition-duration for the two states, resp. specify the duration not equal zero just for the hover state.

(`transition: 0s;` for the *normal* state - because you want it to be 0, when you *return into* this state, from the hover state. Can be implicit, if no transition-duration is already set for that state.)

```css
.invisible{
  opacity: 0;
  /* transition: 0s; */
}

div{
  cursor: pointer;
}

div:hover .invisible{
  opacity: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hover Here</p>
  <p class="invisible">Now you see me</p>
</div>
```